# How I can to test my private field in my class (TypeScript) with using Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have class which has private filed:

```
export class RecordingFeesService {
    private readonly url: string;
    private readonly aud: string;
 
    constructor() {
        this.url = process.env.RECORDING_FEES_URL || "";
        this.aud = process.env.RECORDING_FEES_AUD || "";
    }
}
```

How I can to test my private fields (url, aud) with using Jest?

Comment: That's a property marked as `private` in TypeScript, not a private class field

Comment: You don't test private parts of your class. They're an implementation detail. Either don't make them private (`readonly` should be enough), or expose them through getters, or actually test the behaviour of your class (which the excerpt you've shown doesn't have, so this is a bit pointless).